# MVC2 Html.DropDownList with required field and validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am having heaps of trouble populating a simple drop down box in MVC2. The drop down is a required field so needs validation for this. I will also need to know which option the user selected when the form is posted back.

If anyone has some code snippets for this I would love to see them.

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working. Here is some code snippets:

VIEW MODEL:
public IEnumerable NRCTypeSelect { get; set; }

[Range(1, Int32.MaxValue, ErrorMessage="Required Field")]
public int SelectedNCRType { get; set; }

CONTROLLER:
model.NRCTypeSelect = NCRTypes.ToSelectList("Id", "Name");

EXTENSION METHOD:
public static SelectList ToSelectList(this IEnumerable collection,
                             string dataValueField, string dataTextField)
        {
            return new SelectList(collection, dataValueField, dataTextField);
        }

VIEW:
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedNCRType, Model.NRCTypeSelect, "Select...") %>
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedNCRType, "Required Field") %>